# How to pass return value from component to another one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a const that assembles a get (in another component) and returns me a verification code, this is: **response.data.verifyCode**
This component is called through a submit on another component.

I need to get this value in my another const, which is below:

```
export const sendCode = (id, username) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ some code here });

  return registerAccount
    .sendCode(id, username)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({ payload: response.data.verifyCode });
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return null;
    });
};

export const getCodeAndVerify = (id, userCode) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ some code here });
  
  const getVerifyCode = // I need to get response.data.verifyCode from sendCode above
  
  // I try to use
  // const getVerifyCode = { verifyCode: sendCode() };
  
  // but this returns [object object]

  return registerAccount
    .getCodeAndVerify(id, userCode, getVerifyCode)
    .then(() => {
      // some code here
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // some code here
    });
};
```

That is, I need to get the verifyCode from the return from the superior const and use it in the other const, but I'm not sure how to do that. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is `userCode` the same as `username`?

Comment: @DrewReese No, this comes from another component

Comment: I see. Is `verifyCode` from `sendCode` stored in your redux state, is it this value that you need in the other dispatched `getCodeAndVerify` action? Can you describe, from the UI's perspective, the flow of actions and logic you want to occur?

Comment: Also, what asynchronous action redux middleware are you using?

Comment: @DrewReese Of course, I have a form where I send the username via get and that form returns me the verification code, which comes in response.data.verifyCode. I need to take this answer and submit it in a new form (the getCodeAndVerify) along with other information I get from the user's view. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DrewReese I'm also trying to pass this value in another way, I asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230230/get-value-from-response-and-transfer-to-another-component-in-react

Comment: That other question... seems to basically be the same question here. What is that different?

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous actions (I'm assuming thunks) also receive a `getState` second argument after `dispatch`. Assuming there's a reducer to handle the `verifyCode` send code success, you can access the store and retrieve the `verifyCode` value in `getCodeAndVerify`.

```
export const sendCode = (id, username) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ some code here });

  return registerAccount
    .sendCode(id, username)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'VERIFY_CODE_SUCCESS', // <-- action object needs type
        payload: response.data.verifyCode,
      });
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return null;
    });
};

export const getCodeAndVerify = (id, userCode) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.PASS_CREATION_REQUESTED });
  
  const getVerifyCode = getState().path.to.verifycode; // <-- retrieve from state

  return registerAccount
    .getCodeAndVerify(id, userCode, getVerifyCode)
    .then(() => {
      // some code here
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // some code here
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work, getCodeAndVerify  is activated after submit in another component, I match the digits entered and enter the code received in the previous step

Comment: Thanks for your time! It's getting clear to me, just one more thing: where exactly do I find the .path.to ?

Comment: @CodeG Oh, that would be the path defined by your reducer tree, the exact same path you would use if you were writing a state selector.

Comment: @CodeG An example may be `state.user.registration.verifyCode`. If you've the redux dev tools installed it's the path you traverse when viewing the state.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope you will be rewarded in your life for helping those starting out!

Comment: @CodeG Has my answer helped you and is this solution working for your question/issue?

Comment: Actually not yet, I haven't found a path where the redux states are =(