# Get value from response and transfer to another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I have this handleSubmit that returns me a key (verifyCode) that I should use in another component. How can I pass this **verifyCode** to another component?

```
const SendForm = ({ someValues }) => {

      const handleSubmitAccount = () => {
        dispatch(createAccount(id, username))
        
          .then((response) => {
            // I get this value from data.response, its works
            const { verifyCode } = response;
          })
          .catch(() => {
          });
      };

      return(
         //the form with handleSubmitAccount()
       )
}

export default SendForm;
```

The other component is not a child component, it is loaded after this submit step. But I don't know how to transfer the `const verifyCode`.

This is the view where the components are loaded, it's a step view, one is loaded after the other, I need to get the const verifyCode in FormConfirmation

```
<SendForm onSubmit={handleStepSubmit} onFieldSubmit={handleFieldSubmit} />
<FormConfirmation onSubmit={handleStepSubmit} onFieldSubmit={handleFieldSubmit} />
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You would have to keep some state at a higher level (either a shared parent or global) and it set it there. Where is the other component in relation to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move up the state to a component that has both as children and then pass down a function that updates as a prop

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Updater onClick={() => setValue(value + 1)} />
                <ValueDisplay number={value} />
           </div>
       );
}

 const Updater = (props) => <div onClick={props.onClick}>Update State</div>;
 const ValueDisplay = (props) => <div>{props.number}</div>;
```

Check out the [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

For more complex component structures or where your passing down many levels you may want to look into [reactContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

```
import React from "react";

//Set Default Context
const valueContext = React.createContext({ value: 0, setValue: undefined });

export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
        return (
           <div className="App">
              {/** Pass in state and setter as value */}
              <valueContext.Provider value={{ value: value, setValue }}>
                  <Updater />
                  <ValueDisplay />
              </valueContext.Provider>
         </div>
    );
}

const Updater = () => {
     /** Access context with hook */
     const context = React.useContext(valueContext);
     return (
         <div onClick={() => context.setValue(context.value + 1)}>Update State</div>
     );
};
 const ValueDisplay = () => {
     /** Access context with hook */
     const context = React.useContext(valueContext);
      return <div>{context?.value}</div>;
 };
```